# Twig nested loop

Tags: php, twig

I'm a new Twig user, and I'm with troubles to fill a grid...
I have a entity called "menu", and want to access just some atributes, so I created an array like this:

```
        $itens = array(
                array('name' => 'id', 'label' => 'Id'),
                array('name' => 'parent', 'label' => 'Pai'),
                array('name' => 'name', 'label' => 'Nome'),
                array('name' => 'route', 'label' => 'Rota'),
                array('name' => 'position', 'label' => 'Posição'),
            );
```

So I'm trying to do a nested loop to access this informations... but I don't know how do it. I tryed like this, but obviously it's wrong.

```
    <tbody>
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <tr> 
            {% for item in itens %}
                <td> {{ menu.[item.name] }} </td>
            {% endfor %}                
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

How can I do it???

---

in PHP code, it's looks like it:

```
    foreach $menus as $menu {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach $itens as $item
        echo "<td>".$menu[$item["name"]]."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: I realize this is old, but you did {% for item in itens %} notice 'itens' should be 'items' that seems to be the only difference between this and the accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
<tbody>
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <tr> 
            {% for item in items %}
                <td> {{ menu[item.name] }} </td>
            {% endfor %}                
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes! That's it!!! And I tried it before, but I don't know why didn't works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that twig is very similar to PHP. Your template should look like this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <tr> 
            {% for item in menu %}
                <td> {{ item.name }} </td>
            {% endfor %}                
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Note that this will be translate to something like this in PHP:

```
foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    foreach ($menu as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

More on twig loops [can be found in the twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain well, but I wanna access an array key using information from another array. I think that your answer will access a multi-array, but not what I need... Is it?

Comment: In that case you need to remove the `.` between `menu` and `[item.name]`.

Comment: This is a good example of using nested array values with twig